# Is [complex-families] tag needed?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a [complex-families](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-families) tag for:

> Multiple marriages, step children, adoptions and other extended family scenarios

and it has a tag wiki:

> The notion of the family extends beyond that of a single union and
>   their offspring. Extended relationships, though, can be complex. Use
>   this tag to mark Q&A that is specific to the notion of these extended,
>   complex family scenarios.
>
> If you need to find the English-language term for the relationship
>   between two members of a simple or complex family, the [Steve Morse
>   relationship calculator](http://stevemorse.org/relation/calculator.html) will help.

It was used today on [Incestual representation in genealogy tree](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/16189/incestual-representation-in-genealogy-tree).

As something of a [catch-all](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/catch-all_1) tag, is it needed?

We currently have a separate tag for [adoption](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adoption).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we should get rid of the tag, for this reason: all families are complex. I doubt there is a single genealogist that doesn't have multiple marriages, step children, adoptions and even intermarriage of separate lines in their family tree.

Also, questions should be about one of those things specifically, we are unlikely to get a question dealing with an overall complex family situation that isn't closed as too broad.